# rails functional test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, functional-testing

In the Rails auto-generated functional test (`test/functional/products_controller_test.rb`), I see the following code:

```
class ProductsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  setup do
    @product = products(:one)
    ...
  end

  ...some tests here... 
end
```

The questions that I have are:

1. Where/how is the method call `products()` defined?
2. What does `products(:one)` actually mean? Looking at the code, it probably means "create one product", but how does that work?

N.B. I'm new to Ruby/Rails, apologies if these are a trivial questions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you look in your test/fixtures folder, you'll see a products.yml file.  This is generated automatically when you create a model.  In your test files, `products(:one)` is referring to the product in that file labelled "one".  Fixtures are automatically loaded into the database for tests, and the `products()` method is created as a convenient accessor for those objects.

You can add your own fixture objects as needed, directly in the yml file.